# Scale Web Viewer to fit box (reduce or enlarge to fit)

Tags: filemaker, image

Rather than have to upload/copy across each individual image in my table, I want to display the images based on their image url (which I have). With ordinary images one can check "reduce or enlarge" (Inspector>Format) in order for images to fill the box (even if they are of different sizes). I can use the Web Viewer to create a box which includes the image, but I can't edit Format in the Inspector.

How can I fill the Web Viewer box with the image from a url (which ends in .jpg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the image height and width within the Web Viewer using HTML and CSS. If the ImageURL was referenced in Image::URL you could include it as follows:

```
"data:text/html, <style type='text/css'>

/* Remove margins from the 'html' and 'body' tags */ 

html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} </style>

<img src='" & Image::URL & "' style='width:100%; height:100%;' />"
```

*Uncheck "Allow interaction...", "Display progress bar" and "Display status messages" (in the Web Viewer Setup)*

Comment: This uses the things from @rymored, but moderaters rejected my edit of his post.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the image height and with within the Web Viewer using either HTML or CSS. A simple example of this using inline CSS could be something like this:

```
"data:text/html,
<img src='" & Image::URL & "' style='width:100%; height:100%;' />"
```

Comment: This works great, except a weird thing happens with the border, it puts a border around the top, left and right, but not the bottom!

Comment: hum.. sounds weird. Perhaps it adds borders to all edges, but you only see top and left due to the image scaling ? You could try specifying border width as zero by adding "border:0px;" inside the style-section of the img-tagg.

Comment: unfortunately neither this, nor adding `padding:0px` or `margin:0px` fixes the borders problem... :s

Comment: Still weird! Is it possible to upload screenshot? Maybe I'll get some idea when I see the problem myself.

Comment: the web viewer looks like [this](http://i1058.photobucket.com/albums/t416/hayd--/ScreenShot2012-03-23filemakerwebviewer.png).

Comment: I went back to this, still have the same problem. Before I add the CSS it uses the entire box (but may not fit properly), I add the CSS and it shows as above. I want some small images to display and most of the box is taken up with white space! Weird!

Comment: I removed the margin/padding from the html and body tags, and Bob's your uncle.